# Use of new operator in C++

Tags: c++

I need to use the new operator to dynamically assign the size of an array I have tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
#include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class queue
    {
        int *elt[];//making the pointer array
        int front,rear,size;
        public:
        queue(int a)
        {
            front=rear=-1;
            size=a;
            elt=new int [size];//declaring its size dynamically
        }
        void push(int n);
        int pop();
        void display();
    };
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. What does "doesn't work" even mean? Clarify errors/behavior.

Comment: The error which appears in this code is[Error] incompatible types in assignment of 'int*' to 'int* [0]'

Comment: `vector<int> elt;` ... `queue(int a): elt(a), front(-1), rear(-1) {}` , remove size

Comment: Why not just use a `std::vector`?

Comment: "Use of new operator in C++" - general advice is *don't*.

Comment: If this isn't a homework exercise, you should look into `std::queue<int>` where all these problems are already solved.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `std::vector<int>`? It would make your life easier.

By the way, you have forgotten to define the destructor which deletes the allocated array.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, i'd imagine the reason the op isn't using `std::vector<>` is because they're learning about dynamic memory allocation. Also "By the way, you have forgotten to define the destructor which deletes the allocated array.", it's probably the case that the op needs a destructor but there's no way to tell, a destructor is not the only way to mop up memory allocated from an object.